# question on hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, self-study

Independent random samples of size $N_1 $ = 16 and $N_2$ = 25 from the populations
with standard deviation $\sigma_1$ = 4.8 has the means $\bar{X_1}$ = 18.2.

if the population is not normal and standard deviation $S_1$ is calculated as
$S_1$ = 4.8 of sample size $N_1$ = 16.

I would like to find a 90% confidence interval for the mean $m_1$ of the population, and also I would like to do the test hypothesis If the mean $m_1$ = 15.1, test the null hypothesis $m = 18$ against the alternative hypothesis $m \not= 18$ at 0.01 level of significance.

Finally please help me to give me a clue how to do that if the null hypothesis is rejected, find the maximum integer value of N1 that makes the null hypothesis not to be rejected, or, if the null hypothesis is not rejected, find the minimum integer value of N1 that makes the null hypothesis to be rejected.

Comment: I think there is no way to test mean without either CLT approach or bootstrap

Comment: How can I do with CLT approach? @DaviAmérico

Comment: sample size must be greater than 30 sized regardless it works like your data was normal even if it is not

Comment: Be careful: $30$ isn’t a magic number at which point the central limit theorem “kicks in”. It might be that the convergence “kicks in” well before that or well after that ($30000$ or $30$-million).

Comment: Well, thank you. how can I show what you said in mathematical way? @Dave

Comment: @1190 What exactly do you want to show? What I wrote does not directly address your posted questions. I just wanted to address a rumor written in the comments.